# Why python For in Loop is so slow?

Tags: python

I tested performance `for in` loop in python.
It contains just loop and plus operations. 
But it takes about 0.5secs. How can I do it more faster?

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

val = -1000000
for i in range(2000000):
    val += 1

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

print(elapsed_time) # 0.46402716636657715
```

Comment: Use the `timeit` module to do time trials; it uses more accurate timings and tries to avoid garbage collection and OS scheduler pitfalls (by repeating the experiment).

Comment: For high performance, factor out the loop: just assign `val = 1000000`. This is probably the worst case of premature optimisation I've ever seen!

Comment: @Shashank: pypy is not a silver bullet. Don't use it without testing and only when you are using a *longer running process*; for command-line scripts pypy is only going to be slower.

Comment: You're not testing "performance of the for in loop" (which doesn't mean much - depends on the iterable...), you're testing the performance of a call to `range()` with a big number + performance of the iteration on what `range()` returned for your Python version + performance of integer addition. FWIW  in Python 2.x, `range()` returns a `list`, so you're testing the performance of creating a `list` of 2000000 integers...

Comment: You could always use cython

Comment: @MartijnPieters Noted, and good point! I see now that the JIT compilation takes some time to work.

Comment: The `val` increment is just for example. Actually there are many conditional check logics.

Comment: How fast are you expecting this to be exactly? You're doing **2 MILLION** arithmetic operations. I know I certainly can't do that in less than a second...

Comment: @bruno. I don't think that creating a large list is that slow even in Python 2

Comment: @MadPhysicist nope but if you expect meaningful results you have to make sure you only benchmark the one thing you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some optimizations:

1. (Python 2) Use `xrange()` - this will return an iterator and will not need to first generate the list to allow you to iterate it. In Python 3, `range()` is essentially `xrange()`
2. <strike>Wrap `range(2000000)` in an `iter()` function. I am not sure why, but I saw improvements during my tests</strike>

Comment: `for` implicitly calls`iter` as it is, no? Can you show some example timings with a clear improvement?

Comment: I think I am falling victim to the "garbage collection and OS scheduler pitfalls" mentioned above. Times for both variants range from 0.12s to 0.14s. Adding `iter()` makes no odds